# Custom splitView not calling setDetailItem

Tags: xcode, ios, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm having a problem with a table controller in my custom split view.  I have a `TableViewController` which stands as my popover.  I'm having a problem when selecting an item in the table.

The issue I'm having is that the `setDetailItem` method isn't being called.  In my `TableViewController`, in the `didSelectRow` method I'm setting my `viewControlle`r's `detailItem` to the thing selected, however it isn't registering and instead `detailItem` comes out as null.

Here is what is in my TableViewController, this is the handle for selecting an object in the table.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

/*
 When a row is selected, set the detail view controller's detail item to the item associated with the selected row.
 */
affirmaPDFViewController.detailItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [listOfPDF objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
affirmaPDFViewController.i = indexPath.row;
}
```

Here is what is in my `detailViewController` this what is supposed to be called when detailItem is assigned to a new value.

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {
NSInteger start = 0;


if (detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    [detailItem release];
    detailItem = [newDetailItem retain];

    // Update the view.
    [self configureView];

    start = ((i) * 768);
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(webView1.frame.origin.x + start, webView1.frame.origin.y);
    counter = start / 768;
}

if (popoverController != nil) {
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
}
```

In my `TableViewController.h` file I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class AffirmaPDFViewController;

@interface PDFTableController : UITableViewController {
    AffirmaPDFViewController *affirmaPDFViewController;
    NSMutableArray *listOfPDF;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet AffirmaPDFViewController *affirmaPDFViewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfPDF;

@end
```

and in the implementation file I'm synthesizing the affirmaPDFViewController.

Any ideas as to why setDetailItem isn't being called?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is affirmaPDFViewController != nil ?

Comment: @arclight: affirmaPDFViewController is the name of the class which represents the `detailViewController`

Comment: Yes, i know that, but is it not null? where are you creating an instance of it?

Comment: @arclight: I've edited the question to include the .h of the tableViewController.  Is this what you mean by creating an instance of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code it looks like you are never creating an instance of the your detail controller.

Comment: in your viewDidLoad method probably

Comment: In my appDelegate, I'm creating instances of both the `TableViewController` and the `DetailViewController`.  Would I need to link these in IB?